# Rails: error message trying to install gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm trying to install a (great) Ruby gem called Forem https://github.com/radar/forem it's giving me an error for WillPaginate module. I assume Forem uses will_paginate gem even though I don't see it in its Gemfile

This Forem gem (which is a forum application) normally works for me but this time I'm combining it with another (great) gem Enki (for blogging) that also uses will_paginate https://github.com/xaviershay/enki/blob/master/Gemfile.  Enki normally runs on a 3.0 application but I went through the 3.1 update so it should, at least in that respect, be compatible with Forem, which is also a 3.1 app.

This is the error message I'm getting when I try to install Forem with this commnad

```
 rails g forem:install
```

Anyone know how I might go about trying to fix this?

**Error**

```
   .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/bundler/gems/forem-02eecd37cacc/config/initializers/will_paginate.rb:5:in `alias_method': undefined method `per_page' for module `WillPaginate::ActiveRecord::RelationMethods' (NameError)
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/bundler/gems/forem-02eecd37cacc/config/initializers/will_paginate.rb:5:in `<module:RelationMethods>'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/bundler/gems/forem-02eecd37cacc/config/initializers/will_paginate.rb:4:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/bundler/gems/forem-02eecd37cacc/config/initializers/will_paginate.rb:3:in `<module:WillPaginate>'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/bundler/gems/forem-02eecd37cacc/config/initializers/will_paginate.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/mm/Sites/enki31/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
        from /Users/mmell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Update

Config/initializers/will_paginate.rb

This code is part of the Forem gem https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/master/config/initializers/will_paginate.rb,

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        alias_method :per, :per_page
        alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `config/initializers/will_paginate.rb`?

Comment: What version of will_paginate is being used? The 3.0 final release changed a few of the method names

Comment: In Enki blog, which I installed first, it uses gem 'will_paginate', '= 3.0.pre2', but I can't even see will_paginate in the Forem gem which is raising the error https://github.com/radar/forem

Comment: Even if Forem doesn't have it listed as a dependency, it will still run that initializer if WillPaginate is defined. Could you update WillPaginate to v3.0.3? It appears that `per_page` is defined in [that version](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb).

Comment: that fixed it. if you write an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I guess your are using Rails >= 3.1, and will_paginate is died after Rails 3.0. Check this link out http://gitinit.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/will_paginate-is-broken-in-rails-3-1/